# Hydrapaper will not open - need help interpreting errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and until recently, I used Hydrapaper for my dual monitor setup. It's not imperative that I be able to have separate wallpapers but I am being driven kind of mad by the errors I'm seeing when I try to open Hydrapaper from the terminal. This is what I get:

```sh
michael@michael-Inspiron-7790-AIO:~$ flatpak run org.gabmus.hydrapaper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydrapaper/__main__.py", line 206, in do_command_line
    self.do_activate()
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydrapaper/__main__.py", line 146, in do_activate
    self.window = HydraPaperAppWindow()
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydrapaper/app_window.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.monitors_flowbox = HydraPaperMonitorsFlowbox()
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydrapaper/monitors_flowbox.py", line 132, in __init__
    self.populate()
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydrapaper/monitors_flowbox.py", line 151, in populate
    HydraPaperMonitorsFlowboxItem(m), -1
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydrapaper/monitors_flowbox.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.set_picture()
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydrapaper/monitors_flowbox.py", line 94, in set_picture
    pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(
gi.repository.GLib.GError: gdk-pixbuf-error-quark: Couldn’t recognize the image file format for file “/home/michael/.var/app/org.gabmus.hydrapaper/cache/org.gabmus.hydrapaper/thumbnails//a5debe6ea02641a70325dc008910a85c61765e55906c29dd338e9f63506378a4.png” (3)
```

And as I said, Hydrapaper won't open. It appears in my topbar for a few seconds then disappears. Can anyone suggest a fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux questions should be posted to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact issue, what fixed it for me was going to the file mentioned at the end of the error and deleting it, hydra paper worked perfectly after that